# RTL responsive table

Tags: css, responsive-design, right-to-left

I am almost newbie to `CSS`

I have found a responsive table from [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php) site. which I want to use it in my application.

The problem is I don't how to make it Right To Left (headers must be at the right of the page and values at the left) when I make the table small and it converts from table to a `Block`.

This is its `CSS` Code:

```
<style>

/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
    td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
    td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
    td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
    td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
    td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
    td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    body { 
        padding: 0; 
        margin: 0; 
        width: 320px; }
    }

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body { 
        width: 495px; 
    }
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

1. for `td`, change `padding-left` to `padding-right`.
2. for `td:before`, change `left` to `right`, and `padding-right` to `padding-left`.
3. add `text-align: right` to `table`.

**Update:** If you want your cells to wrap in narrow widths: first, remove `padding-right` from `td`, then change the `td:before` CSS to the following:

```
td:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Here's a complete example that covers more edge cases: http://jsbin.com/ASOnaXug/2

Comment: Shall I add `td:after`?

Comment: You won't need a `td:after`, `td:before` would work since it's absolutely positioned.

Comment: Thanks. I made `text-align` of the table to left and it worked. But I have another problem if you can help me as well. when I make the screen size very small I want both header and value text to be wrapped. I changed the `white-space:normal` in `td:before` and the headers are wrapping now. but the problem is that it becomes bigger than the row height. is that possible to make the rows height to something like `auto`??

Comment: You're gonna have to do a few changes for that. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry @myajouri. it worked. but both headers and values are aligned to left now. the headers must be at right of the page and the values at the left.

Comment: are you setting the direction to be `dir="RTL"` in your document?

Comment: I am using Angularjs and Bootstrap-RTL-3.0 in my application. as you know bootstrap-rtl makes my whole document right to left.

Comment: In that case, try changing `td:before` to `td:after`.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I have just posted a complete example in my answer, which cover more edge cases.

Comment: Sorry dude again! :(  it is working fine in computer. when I resize the page everything is fine. but when I use it in my smartphone, it just occupies half of the screen size. and when I rotate my smartphone, I have to refresh my website to see the effects. (the second problem is not really important) I have tested that in 10.1" and 7" tablets

Comment: You need to set the initial viewport scale to 1. Add this `meta` tag in `head`: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">` I will update the JSbin in my answer so you can see it live.